# Variável indefinida no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou aprendendo CodeIgniter e tentando passar um array para a View através do meu controller e quando chamo esse array na view é me apresentado como indefinido.

Esse é o meu controller:

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Consulta extends CI_Controller {
        public function index() {
            $this->load->view("index");
        }
        public function listar_consultas() {
            $this->load->view("listar");
        }

        public function salvar_consulta() {
            $this->load->model("model_marcar_consulta");
            if ($this->model_marcar_consulta->salvar_dados()) {
                $this->load->view("sucesso");
            } else {
                $this->load->view("erro");
            }
        }

        public function listando_consultas() {
            $this->load->model("model_marcar_consulta");
            $consulta = $this->model_marcar_consulta->retorna_lista_consulta();
            $variaveis["consulta"] = $consulta;
            $this->load->view("listar", $variaveis);
        }
    }
?>
```

E essa é a minha View:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Especialidade</td>
        <td>Data de Marcação</td>
        <td>Horario de Marcação</td>
        <td>Observação</td>
        <td>Data de públicação</td>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($consulta -> result() as $linha): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $linha->id ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Realmente não estou entendendo este erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: consulta
>
> Filename: views/listar.php
>
> Line Number: 21
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\marcar_consulta\application\views\listar.php on line 21

Comment: Tu já conferiu o retorno do método `$this->model_marcar_consulta->retorna_lista_consulta()`?

Comment: Oi, valdiney, dá um confere nas [**edições da pergunta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/32788/revisions) para ver como formatar um post aqui no stack :)

Comment: Se você postar o código da sua model seria mais fácil te ajudar. Pois sem saber o que está codificado lá temos que nos guiar por deduções.

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\marcar_consulta\application\views\listar.php on line 21

Na sua *view* você usa `$consulta-> result()`, mas o erro informa que `$consulta` não é um objeto. Pelo visto o seu modelo está retornando um array com o resultado da operação - com `$query->result()`, e não a instãncia do DB.

1) Se o seu modelo estiver executando a query com `$this->db->get()->result()`, seu loop deve fazer referência a objeto:

```
<?php foreach($consulta as $linha): ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $linha->id ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

2) Para usar o resultado em forma de array, use `$this->db->get()->result_array()`

```
<?php foreach($consulta as $linha): ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $linha['id'] ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

<sub>Mais exemplos na [*DOC*](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) do Codeigniter sobre resultados de operações DB.</sub>